# CONCAT() inside GROUP_CONCAT() with count

Tags: mysql, sql, concatenation, group-concat

I am trying to get results with group_concat, concat and count functions in MySQL but it gives me error. 
here is my table

[image]

First, when I try to get count and status with concat, it works fine.

```
$query="SELECT CONCAT(`status`,':',count(status)) FROM `mytable` GROUP BY status"
```

**output:** 
Hold:2 
Completed:3 
Cancelled:2

It's all fine till here. Now I want this output in one row. So I tried using GROUP_CONCAT().

```
$query="SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(`status`,':',count(status)) SEPARATOR ',') as rowString FROM `mytable` GROUP BY status"
```

but now its giving me error *" Invalid use of group functions"*

**Note:** the same query works if I replace count(status) with some other field from table ( without count). The `count()` function is causing some problem when used in this manner.

**Desired Output**

Hold:2,Completed:3,Cancelled:2

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Simply said you can't nest anny [aggregate (GROUP BY) functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html) like this  `GROUP_CONCAT(COUNT())` .. I advice to to read [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) and provide table data as text formatted data (no Images) and expected results.

Comment: Thank You Brabaros

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot nest aggregation functions (`count()` is in the arguments to `group_conat()`). One solution is to select from a nested subquery.

```
SELECT group_concat(status, ':', count SEPARATOR ',') rowstring
       FROM (SELECT status,
                    count(*) count
                    FROM mytable
                    GROUP BY status) x;
```

Comment: @Pandurang Mind the default max `GROUP_CONCAT` length of 1024 like mentioned in the manual.. Running something like this `SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = @@max_allowed_packet;` before this query is  most likely required in the future when the table becomes larger or more status groups are added.