# Using group concat in mysql

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table called events with columns as dt and type

I am trying to use GROUP_CONCAT but getting error:

```
select concat('Q', QUARTER (dt), "", "", RIGHT (YEAR (dt), 2)) as period,
GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(type, '=', COUNT(*)) ORDER BY COUNT(*) desc, type asc SEPARATOR ';') events
from events
where YEAR (dt) = 2021
GROUP BY QUARTER (dt), YEAR(dt)
ORDER BY period asc;
```

The error says:
At line 1 : Invalid use of group function

I have followed the link [CONCAT() inside GROUP_CONCAT() with count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54278934/concat-inside-group-concat-with-count) and changed my query like this:

```
select concat('Q', QUARTER (dt), "", RIGHT (YEAR (dt), 2)) as period, (select GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(type, '=', c) SEPARATOR ';') sub
from (select count(*) as c from events order by count(*) desc_type asc) s
)
from events
where YEAR(dt) = 2021
GROUP BY QUARTER (dt), YEAR (dt)
ORDER BY period asc;
```

Now I am getting syntax error.